# Is there a way to deliver push notifications in iOS 11 during Guided Access?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios11, guided-access

Our iPad app relies on silent push notifications to trigger certain events, and is used by many of our users in **Guided Access** mode. This has worked well until iOS 11 which now seems to block delivery of push notifications while Guided Access is enabled.

I've tried a variety of different payloads according to the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH10-SW8) (such as content-available, alert, sound, badge etc.), but I can't get anything to be delivered while Guided Access is enabled. This isn't necessarily a bug, but may in fact be the new intended behaviour.

Is there a way I can configure a notification so that it is delivered during guided access?

For what it's worth I raised a Technical Support Incident for this issue with Apple, who promptly refunded my ticket and asked me to report a bug instead. There has been no feedback from the bug report yet.

Comment: Are you using `UserNotifications` framework and `UNUserNotificationCenter`? The older way of using `AppDelegate` callbacks and `[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotifications]` is deprecated and could potentially be having issues in iOS 11 in Guide Access mode.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I can confirm that we are using the UserNotifications framework present in iOS 10 and above.

Comment: I confirm the same in our project.

Comment: If your app is in the foreground, why not create your own push system, such like c/s mode bsd socket to reach your goal. There are lots samples: xmppframework on the iOS side, openfire on the server side.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, we ended up going down the path of websockets which is working well (although came with it's own challenges).

Comment: @Kevin Cao, your method works, turn it into an answer for people to reference

Comment: I can confirm this is also a problem in Single App Mode.

Comment: Push notifications work for Core Data with iCloud apps (not CloudKit) in Guided Access Mode. So Apple hasn't disabled push notifications entirely. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a design decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be fixed in the newest iOS 11.2.5 beta 4. Confirmed with Guided Access and Single App Mode using CloudKit push notifications.

Comment: We've verified this with behaviour with our own app.  All indications are this was nothing more than an iOS bug.

Comment: What about using Google Cloud Function? Will the device receive the notification to in kiosk / single app mode too? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your app is in the foreground, you can create your own push system using c/s mode BSD socket to reach your goal. 
There are good sample like xmppframework on the iOS side and openfire on the server side.

Comment: While I appreciate the suggestion, I'm reluctant to mark this as the answer because I really wanted a definitive answer on whether or not notifications can be delivered during Guided Access.