# iOS11: Is it possible to launch notification when device is under guided access?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, guided-access

I have a code that allows the device to run an update. It works perfectly when the ipad is not under guided access for information under iOS11 (and it worked under iOS10 & guided accesss):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
...
      UNMutableNotificationContent* content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
        content.title = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Update!" arguments:nil];
        content.body = [NSString localizedUserNotificationStringForKey:@"Update!"
                                                             arguments:nil];

        // Configure the trigger for a 7am update.
        NSDateComponents* date = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        date.hour = 18;
        date.minute = 31;
        UNCalendarNotificationTrigger* trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
                                                  triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:date repeats:NO];

        // Create the request object.
        UNNotificationRequest* request = [UNNotificationRequest
                                          requestWithIdentifier:@"update" content:content trigger:trigger];

        UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
            }
        }];
    }

    - (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center
           willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification
             withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
        // Update the app interface directly.
        NSLog(@"");
        // Play a sound.
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);
    }
```

I found that [Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256264/is-there-a-way-to-deliver-push-notifications-in-ios-11-during-guided-access), but no exhaustive explanations to accomplish it:

Is it possible under iOS11 to launch notification on guided access?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It appears this was nothing more than an iOS bug which has been fixed in iOS 11.2.5 beta 4. Please see my own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47256264/is-there-a-way-to-deliver-push-notifications-in-ios-11-during-guided-access) for more information.

If you can wait until iOS 11.2.5 is released (which will hopefully be soon [according to Apple](https://www.apple.com/iphone-battery-and-performance/)) the issue should just resolve itself. Otherwise you'll need to investigate something like a sockets system instead.

Comment: Thx, I am going to test :D